# calling javascript function of bool type

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a Page Method using AJAX.
See the code

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_upload" runat="server" CssClass="btnEffects" Text="Upload" 
        onclick="btn_upload_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
```

Validate method is supposed to return true/false.
The code for Validate method is

```
<script language="javascript">

function Validate()
{   
   var filename = $get('<%= txt_filename.ClientID %>').value;
   PageMethods.IsValidFile(filename,OnSuccess, OnFailure); 
  // IsValidFile is a Page Method of bool return type
}

function OnSuccess(result) 
{
   if ( !result)
   {     
     alert('File '+ $get('<%= txt_filename.ClientID %>').value + ' does not exist');
     return false;
   }
   else
   {      
    return true;
   }
}
function OnFailure(error) 
{   
}
</script>
```

My problem is that even after showing the alert 'File somefilename does not exist'.
The whole page refrshes (i.e, postback happens)

Answer (score 0):

You are running an asyncronous operation and still expecting it to block your call and wait for the response, this is one workaround that i have seen in the past, you hide your submit button and create another button that calls your ajax request, in the success of this request you click you hidden button, something like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_upload_dummy" runat="server" CssClass="btnEffects" Text="Upload"          OnClientClick="Validate();" />  


<asp:Button ID="btn_upload" runat="server" CssClass="btnEffects" style='display:none;' Text="Upload"          onclick="btn_upload_Click"  />  


<script language="javascript">  
function Validate() 
{       
    var filename = $get('<%=txt_filename.ClientID %>').value;    
    PageMethods.IsValidFile(filename,OnSuccess, OnFailure);    
    // IsValidFile is a Page Method of bool return type 
}  

function OnSuccess(result)  
{
    if ( !result)    
    {           
         alert('File '+ $get('<%=txt_filename.ClientID %>').value + ' does not exist');      
         return false;    
     }        
     else    
    {           
        var btn = $get('<%btn_upload.ClientID');
        var clicker = btn.click ? btn.click : btn.onclick;
        clicker();    
    } 
} 


</script>
```

Comment: "in the success of this request you click you hidden button". How to do this perticular call?

Comment: This will help in achieving the functionality yet the page refresh will happen when the dummy button is clicked.